# Fingerprint Sensor in Raspberry Pi with DeepinOS

Tags: raspberry-pi, fingerprint

I have a raspberry Pi 2 + that I want to run Deepin OS on. Deepen 15.x has a new fingerprint reader feature. For those of you who don't know, Deepin is made as a standalone distro as well as is the main OS for Huawei's Matebooks. Evidently, the fingerprint reader feature is built into the Matebooks. Is there a way to connect a fingerprint reader (through GPIO or whatever) and get the built in Deepin feature working?